# How to use jetty-runner to deploy a war file which is not using maven

Tags: maven, jetty, war

Hi recently i heard that we can use jetty-runner to deploy a war file.But my question is can we use this to deploy a war file which uses no maven.Can we use jetty-runner to deploy any war files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jetty-runner is separate from maven, you just need to point at a war file

http://blogs.webtide.com/janb/entry/jetty_runner

cheers

Comment: i just have downloaded the jetty-runner.jar file and put it into the bin folder of java but when i commanding like this  java -jar jetty-runner.jar --help   it shows cant access jetty can you tell me how could i do this

Comment: you don't put it in the bin dir of java, you just put it into a directory and then run directly against it. ie, put it in your current directory and then run that command....or change your path to find the file, java -jar $JAVA_HOME/bin/jetty-runner.jar (really not supposed to go there though)